# AWS EKS cloud-control-manager: "Found multiple subnets in AZ" but they are the wrong ones

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have an EKS cluster (v.1.29) deployed on AWS with 2 private and 2 public subnets for EKS, in 2 different AZs each.

The private subnets are tagged with:

- `kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb = 1`
- `kubernetes.io/cluster/[CLUSTER_NAME] = "owned"`

And the public subnets are tagged with:

- `kubernetes.io/role/elb = 1`
- `kubernetes.io/cluster/[CLUSTER_NAME] = "owned"`

I've installed the `aws-load-balancer-controller` via helm and now I want to deploy a NLB on my private EKS subnets. My service should be correctly annotated with

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "nlb",
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: "internal",
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: "ip"
```

The NLB is deployed on the correct private subnets but I see the following warnings in my cloud-control-manager logs:

```
aws.go:3631] Found multiple subnets in AZ "eu-central-1a"; choosing "subnet-[FIRST_WRONG_SUBNET]" between subnets "subnet-[FIRST_WRONG_SUBNET]" and "subnet-[SECOND_WRONG_SUBNET]"
```

These subnets may be in the correct AZ and same VPC but they don't have to anything with EKS and also don't have any kubernetes tags. According to my understanding and taking a peek [at the code](https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-aws/blob/64508eddd57cc542bf429d59ed51cea10d7b0f92/pkg/providers/v1/aws.go#L3626C1-L3626C1) the `cloud-control-manager` shouldn't even consider these other subnets as these are not tagged.

How can I resolve those warnings?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the annotation:

```
service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-subnets:
```

which specifies the Availability Zone the NLB will route traffic to.